# Chrome Extension, can't visualize the icon in the toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First of all, I'm trying to use the new manifest 3, but there are no samples out there so it's difficult to understand how develop a chrome extension.

I'm trying to build a basic Hello world app, and i want to have an icon on the toolbar so when the user clicks it, a message "hello" shows up on the page.

This second part is easy as I already know how to inject the code, but the problem is that I cannot seem to see the app icon in my tool bar...

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My App Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "do something",
    "short_name": "My App Name",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["src/bg/background.css"],
        "js": ["src/bg/background.js", "js/jquery/jquery.min.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_title": "My App Name",
        "default_icon":
        {
            "16": "icons/icon16.png",
            "32": "icons/icon32.png",
            "48": "icons/icon48.png"
        }
    }
}
```

not sure what I need to add to see the icon

FYI I'm testing it locally ...i'm not sure if the local version acts differently from a packeged final version...

Comment: Your manifest is MV2 not MV3. In MV3 you'll need to replace browser_action with `action`, see also [MV3 migration](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) in the documentation. Also use `"default_popup": "popup.html"` there instead of declarativeContent for a start because it's simpler. Note that extension pages are granted access to `chrome` API only if they're opened properly (e.g. via a click on the extension icon) so they have a chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: I see you load background.js as a content script which is a bad idea because the background script is a script that runs in a special background context of the extension so either declare a `background` section properly in manifest.json or rename the script to avoid the ambiguity. P.S. Generally you can use any [MV2 sample extension](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive) and convert it per the migration guide.